# std::uniform_real_distribution regenerating same random number

Tags: c++, c++11, random, uniform-distribution

In running the code below, the first half of `arr` equals the last half.  Why?  I even tried various seeds, e.g. `std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()`. Thanks.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>


template<typename DistributionType>
class Rng 
{
public:
        template<typename ...Args>
        Rng(Args&&... args) : dist(args...) { } 

        typename DistributionType::result_type operator()()
        {
                return dist(gen);
        }

private:
        std::default_random_engine gen;

        DistributionType dist;
};


class UniformRealRng : public Rng<std::uniform_real_distribution<double>>
{
public:
        UniformRealRng(const double a, const double b) : Rng(a, b) { } 
};

int main()
{
        constexpr int sz = 6;
        constexpr int k  = sz / 2;
        double arr[sz];

        UniformRealRng rng(0.0, 1.0);
        std::generate(arr, arr + k, rng);
        std::generate(arr + k, arr + sz, rng);

        for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        {
                std::cout << arr[i];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is factually correct but it doesn't solve the problem.
It only produces a compilation error when mistakenly(?) one tries to copy the random number generator.

It turns out that the code can be made to be semantically correct by using the `std::reference_wrapper` library features.

```
    std::generate(arr, arr + k, std::ref(rng));
    std::generate(arr + k, arr + sz, std::ref(rng));
```

In this way you are basically forcing to pass the argument by reference.
*Luckily* the reference wrapper overloads the `operator()` and therefore can be used for the generator without any additional code.

Complete code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <functional> //ref

template<typename DistributionType>
class Rng 
{
public:
        template<typename ...Args>
        Rng(Args&&... args) : dist(args...) { } 
//      Rng(Rng&)             = delete;  // this is not needed for it to work 
//      Rng& operator=(Rng&)  = delete;  // you MAY want to copy the generator
        typename DistributionType::result_type operator()()
        {
                return dist(gen);
        }

private:
        std::default_random_engine gen;

        DistributionType dist;
};


class UniformRealRng : public Rng<std::uniform_real_distribution<double>>
{
public:
        UniformRealRng(const double a, const double b) : Rng(a, b) { } 
};

int main()
{
        constexpr int sz = 6;
        constexpr int k  = sz / 2;
        double arr[sz];

        UniformRealRng rng(0.0, 1.0);
        std::generate(arr, arr + k, std::ref(rng));
        std::generate(arr + k, arr + sz, std::ref(rng));

        for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        {
                std::cout << arr[i];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::generate` takes its third argument by value, so `rng` was being copied.

For safety, one could delete copying:

```
Rng(Rng&)             = delete;   
Rng& operator=(Rng&)  = delete;
```